# Access to old m2m_data in django deserialized object with a custom m2m 'through'

Tags: django, django-orm, django-serializer

How can I access an old m2m_data in deserialized Django model instance if m2m relation was made with a custom 'through'?

An m2m_data field in deserialized object does not contain m2m fields with a custom 'through', and if I try to access that field in deserialized_object.object.filed - ORM makes queries to DB and returns current records for that m2m relation...

Answer (score 0):

Solution is - custom serializer;
just remove this line from handle_m2m_field method of serializer what you prefer to use:

```
    if field.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
```